# InfluxDB: Group rows with same timestamp

Tags: influxdb, influxql

Assume a DB with the following data records:

```
2018-04-12T00:00:00Z value=1000 [series=distance]
2018-04-12T00:00:00Z value=10   [series=signal_quality]
2018-04-12T00:01:00Z value=1100 [series=distance]
2018-04-12T00:01:00Z value=0    [series=signal_quality]
```

There is one field called `value`. Square brackets denote the tags (further tags omitted). As you can see, the data is captured in *different* data records instead of using multiple fields on the *same* record.

**Given the above structure, how can I query the time series of distances, filtered by signal quality?** The goal is to only get distance data points back when the signal quality is above a fixed threshold (e.g. 5).

Comment: This can hardly be done as InfluxDB doesn't have joins. It might be possible with kapacitor, but that's another story. It would be much easier to add signal_quality_value field to distance series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Given the above structure", there's no way to do it in plain InfluxDB.

Please keep in mind - Influx is NONE of a relational DB, it's different, despite query language looks familiar.

Again, given *that structure* - you can proceed with Kapacitor, as it was already mentioned.

But I strongly suggest you to rethink the structure, if it is possible, if you're able to control the way the metrics are collected.

If that is not an option - here's the way: spin a simple job in Kapacitor that will just join the two points into one basing on time ([check this out for how](https://docs.influxdata.com/kapacitor/v1.5/nodes/join_node/)), and then drop it into new measurement.

The data point would look like this, then:

`DistanceQualityTogether,tag1=if,tag2=you,tag2=need,tag4=em distance=1000,signal_quality=10 2018-04-12T00:00:00Z`

The rest is oblivious with such a measurement.

But again, if you can configure your metrics to be sent like this - better do it.